# How to get transaction ID from response in Square Payment

Tags: php, payment-gateway, square

I am very new in square payment.
I get response below. Now I need transaction ID from this response.
What's the best way to get it from this response?

```
---->Array
(
    [*errors] => 
    [*transaction] => SquareConnect\Model\Transaction Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 14bad261-60a6-56d7-6422-3ec8b7cdd10e
            [location_id:protected] => CBASEGb8XMvdzZkrjf0H3PiMRi8gAQ
            [created_at:protected] => 2018-03-12T10:23:33Z
            [tenders:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SquareConnect\Model\Tender Object
                        (
                            [id:protected] => 7924ab32-9544-5139-673e-8ff5d0767858
                            [location_id:protected] => CBASEGb8XMvdzZkrjf0H3PiMRi8gAQ
                            [transaction_id:protected] => 14bad261-60a6-56d7-6422-3ec8b7cdd10e
                            [created_at:protected] => 2018-03-12T10:23:33Z
                            [note:protected] => Online Transaction
                            [amount_money:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\Money Object
                                (
                                    [amount:protected] => 100
                                    [currency:protected] => USD
                                )

                            [tip_money:protected] => 
                            [processing_fee_money:protected] => 
                            [customer_id:protected] => 
                            [type:protected] => CARD
                            [card_details:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\TenderCardDetails Object
                                (
                                    [status:protected] => CAPTURED
                                    [card:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\Card Object
                                        (
                                            [id:protected] => 
                                            [card_brand:protected] => VISA
                                            [last_4:protected] => 1111
                                            [exp_month:protected] => 
                                            [exp_year:protected] => 
                                            [cardholder_name:protected] => 
                                            [billing_address:protected] => 
                                            [fingerprint:protected] => 9334946c94d2a20de8b1e267cc221a23298daed43b44621b4f44a0d032f0fc88
                                        )

                                    [entry_method:protected] => KEYED
                                )

                            [cash_details:protected] => 
                            [additional_recipients:protected] => 
                        )

                )
```

Comment: So... `$response['transaction']->id` ?

Comment: on local works this : $result['transaction']['tenders'][0]['transaction_id']    but not for secure response

Answer (score -1):

```
$result->getTransaction()->getId();
```